# Submit form after user tweet

Tags: regex, forms, twitter

I have an idea and I'm not sure if it'll work (and I hope this is the appropriate place to ask this question).

Basically, what I'm trying to do is grab a user's tweet (one user in particular), and if the tweet matches a RegEx pattern, grab a part of it and submit a form on another page. The form has two parts, the first part is for the information, and the second is just a confirmation.

The only two languages I know that would have this capability (to my knowledge) are PHP and Java. Unfortunately my knowledge of PHP is fairly mediocre and Java would be pretty basic. This being said I'd need to do some research.

First of all, is what I want to do even possible, and secondly, what would I have to be looking at to pull this off? (I'm open to learning a similar language if necessary)

Comment: This question is too broad and indeed you would have to do basic research. Looks into the twitter API.

Comment: @PeeHaa well I know you can grab tweets with PHP. I'm more worried about the whole form situation.

Comment: If you are trying to post to some external form look into curl.